# How to pin a user-specific instance of Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar

In Google Chrome, under Settings, I created an addition user.  So there is `First User` and `Dad`.  I'd like to pin 2 copies of Chrome to the taskbar, so that one opens Chrome with `First User` and the other opens the `Dad` user.  I'd like each one to have a different icon.

How can I pull this off?

Comment: [How to start different profiles with Google Chrome when startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/201885/how-to-start-different-profiles-with-google-chrome-when-startup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully adopted the approach form SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10541484/1953175 - this allows to create several independent Chrome instances at once (I need that for testing purposes).

The key point is to modify shortcut for launching Chrome:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir="[path to folder]"`

Sure thing you have your own path, but the details are thoroughly described in the original answer.