# What exactly are the differences between Chrome users and browser profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles, command-line-arguments, multiple-users

Google Chrome supports both [multiple users](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) and [multiple browser user profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214). To add to the confusion, the end of the latter Google Support page reads:

> Creating a new Chrome user is another quick way to create a new browser user profile. [Learn how to add a new user in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) [N.B. which links to the page on multiple users]

What exactly are the differences and pros & cons of each, aside from how they're created?

[Labnol](https://www.labnol.org/software/create-family-profiles-in-google-chrome/4394/) seems to superficially cover the topic, implying in a March 2012 article there *is* a difference in password and browsing history storage. I've created a profile via Chrome's Settings mechanism, and a new directory was created in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\`. That's exactly what Labnol instructs you to do the hard way. That new profile did not inherit anything from the Default profile. The history was empty, and there were no passwords stored. This suggests that the Labnol article is wrong. It instructs on to copy the Default profile directory, which will, of course, copy the history. Finally, the claim that "Unlike Firefox that ships with a Profile Manager, you can only manually create user profiles in Google Chrome.", is patently obsolete.

Furthermore, Chrome 26 created a shortcut on the desktop launching `chrome.exe` with the `--profile-directory` parameter, not with the `--user-data-dir` suggested by Labnol. Both are mentioned in the [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/):

1. `--user-data-dir` Directory where the browser stores the user profile.
2. `--profile-directory` Selects directory of profile to associate with the first browser launched.

Answer (score 1):

System users vs local settings profiles

A <strike>User</strike> Profile is system specific, stored in its User folder through that %LOCALAPPDATA%. Meaning that if you log on into Windows with two different users you cannot access eachother's <strike>user</strike> profile folder without prior linking or other form of permission access and setup.

C:\Users\Adam\
C:\Users\Eve\

Eve can't load Adam's cookies or saved passwords, nor vice-versa.

Basically it ties those <strike>User</strike> Profile folders in Adam and Eve to the local security layer and permissions defined for each user in questions, including Admins.

The <strike>Browser profiles</strike> in-browser User is in case you have need for a different set of settings for a site or just want a fresh <strike>profile</strike> without extensions to test or browse in case some extensions make trouble.

For example: you don't want to create a new system User for your sister just so she can go on Facebook and have to switch between accounts through the shut down button or task manager, you'll use your own user, so if you both want to log onto Facebook, each with your own account, at the same time, you have to create a new <strike>browser profile</strike> in-browser User. In the Default <strike>profile</strike> in-browser User you are logged in with yours and you have your own settings, cookies, passwords and in the second <strike>profile</strike> in-browser User your sister will get her own privileges without interference, both of them can run simultaneously, switching between them is simpler and faster. All extensions need to be installed again in the second profile if need be.

Fixed meaning, typically Google should have used the 'profile' and 'user' words accordingly, a user is a private account, similar to the local user account, and a profile a second separation entity which is working within the same local user account. Mozilla named them accordingly: profiles, Google named them Users they should have named them in-browser Users if they wanted to stick with the word.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. What you describe are Windows users (which lead to completely different Google Chrome users/profiles/whatever because of different `c:\users\<username>\Google\Chrome` directories they're stored in, while the confusion I ran into is [Chrome's own user profiles system](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824). Do you have a citation?

Comment: The confusion you might have come from not understanding the multiple users explanation page you've linked to. still writing...

Comment: "Manage multiple users on Chrome" shows how to create multiple users, each of those will be stored in the same profile location. Create a new browser user profile shows exactly that, how to create/restore/backup a profile location where each profile's users are stored, it can only be changed if a new system user is used or if used like this --user-data-dir=C:\foo where C:\foo is the equivalent of 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data' stored on a thumb drive for ex or in a TrueCrypt container.

Comment: Good explanation! It's very hard to read though due to the many striked out words.