# Prevent profile change / saved login after others login to their Google Account

Tags: google-chrome

Other people login to their Gmail account using my profile, and aren't considerate enough to logout. Because both the Gmail account and Chrome profile are in sync, logging into their Gmail account also switches the Google Chrome profile to their Google Accounts profile.

When I next open the browser, I am presented with their synced bookmarks, settings, history etc.

I know it's trivial for me to logout from their account and login to mine, but it's become enough of an annoyance that I'd like to attack the problem at the source.

Ideally, when I next open the browser, I would like to see no trace of their activity -- the profile should be restored to mine, and I should be logged in to all Google services using my account.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't let people login to your computer with your account. That's security 101.

Comment: @Tetsujin not really something I can control ATM.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Launch Chrome using a different profile and/or Incognito mode.  In other words launch Chrome using a different profile, so your Chrome user profile, isn't used by other people.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there any way at the browser level to force other people to launch different accounts using a different profile / Incognito mode? Otherwise, getting people to change their behavior is often a lost cause.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Sure;  Change the Chrome shortcut to launch a specific profile.

Comment: @Ramhound This seems like the way to go. Please post as an answer.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/201885/how-to-start-different-profiles-with-google-chrome-when-startup) should still work.

Comment: @Ramhound Is my question a duplicate of the one you referenced?

Comment: @ZevSpitz - If an answer to the question, answers your question, then it's a duplicate.  If there is something missing from an existing answer, edit your question, and narrow the question down. The question as it's written currently isn't much more than "how do I Chrome so it uses a different chrome profile" based on your comment saying launching a different Chrome profile would be a acceptable solution

Answer (score 1):

[As answered over on the Webapps stack site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124509/206273)

> I finally figured out a way to make Chrome sign out on closing the
> browser. There are two settings that need to be set:
>
> Cookies: In Chrome go to settings...click Advanced...click Content
> settings...click cookies..."keep local data only until you close your
> browser" should be turned ON.
>
> System setting: In Chrome go to settings...click Advanced...scroll to
> system..."continue running background apps when Google Chrome is
> closed" should be turned OFF.
>
> Both of these need to be set as indicated for this to work.
>
> I am no expert but this has worked for me. I have closed the browser
> and it has required me to login to Google.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to login myself each time.

Comment: I think you're out of luck in that case, since your goals here are mutually exclusive. If it's logging in as you, it's going to stay logged in as you until you log out (or force it to log out by following these steps). I'd suggest a password manager of some kind so it's at least not such a pain to log back in every time.